# Android - Action bar at top and tabs at bottom of the page

Tags: android

I am a novice Android developer. I have just started learning Android programming. I want to know whether it is possible to add Action Bar with Action Icons at top of the page and Tabs at bottom of the page! If so someone please guide me how to implement a code for it!

Thanks in advance,
UDAY

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can add action buttons on the bottom, only if there is no room at the top, however to do this, you should activate "split" option of your action bar in activity:

To enable split action bar when using the support library, you must do two things:

Add `uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` to each `<activity>` element or to the  element. This attribute is understood only by API level 14 and higher (it is ignored by older versions).
To support older versions, add a `<meta-data>` element as a child of each  element that declares the same value for `"android.support.UI_OPTIONS"`

This is quote from official docs, I recommend you to read more on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

By the way, if you want to support older versions of android sdk (less than 3) use **ActionBarSherlock** it is third-party lib, but it has very similar ip to official actionbar and supports any version of android sdk. To learn more about it visit [actionBarSherlock Home Page](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes

Read android documentation about Actionbars
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html
And you see there is something called Bottom bars.

They should not be used for navigation tho as you can read on at
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html