# Tab Bar in Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

With the help of these program, I created the Tabs. you can look at a below Codes.

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
 package com.sit.fth.activity;

    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.WindowManager;


    public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements
            VideoFragment.OnVideoSelectedListener,

            AboutFragment.OnAboutFragmentSelectedListener,

            AnnouncenentFragment.OnAnnouncementSelectedListener,

            GalleryFragment.OnGalItemSelectedListener,

            MagzineFragment.OnMagzineSelectedListener {

        private ActionBar actionabar;
        private ViewPager viewpager;
        private LiveStreamFragment liveStreamFragment;
        private AppData appData;
        private FragmentManager fm;
        private MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter;
        // private HomeBaseFragment fragment;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
            super.onCreate(arg0);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            appData = ((GemsApplication) this.getApplication()).getAppData();


            actionabar = getActionBar();
            actionabar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



            liveStreamFragment = new LiveStreamFragment();

            viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

            /** Defining a listener for pageChange */
            ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    super.onPageSelected(position);
                    actionabar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            };

            /** Setting the pageChange listner to the viewPager */
            viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

            /** Creating an instance of FragmentPagerAdapter */
            fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

            viewpager.setAdapter(fragmentPagerAdapter);
            actionabar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

            /** Defining tab listener */
            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0,
                        android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,
                        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
                    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab,
                        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

                }
            };


                    Tab tab = actionabar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.str_home))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener);
                    actionabar.addTab(tab);
                    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.str_video))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener);
                    actionabar.addTab(tab);
                    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.str_gal))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener);
                    actionabar.addTab(tab);
                    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.str_announcements))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener);
                    actionabar.addTab(tab);

                    tab = actionabar.newTab()
                            .setText(getString(R.string.str_magazines))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener);
                    actionabar.addTab(tab);

                    tab = actionabar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.str_conduct))
                            .setTabListener(tabListener);
                    actionabar.addTab(tab);  


        }
    }
```

I need to move a tab to the bottom of the screen.I am getting confused because I add a `tabs` with the help of `HomeActivity.java coding not from xml layout`.

I doesn't know how to move the tab to the bottom of the screen.Anybody can help me with these.Thank You.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18182776/android-action-bar-at-top-and-tabs-at-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: You can't move the ActionBar tabs at the bottom(and it also goes against android's design principles). You can, however, use normal tabs and put them at the bottom yourself.

Comment: @Luksprog Thank you for your answer.I already use a normal tabs.But, in that I doesn't get a swipe view.Is there any possibility to get a swipe tabs at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: In the code you posted it seems that you set the tabs on the ActionBar, I also don't see any TabHost widgets that would indicate otherwise. As I said, with a normal TabHost you can place the tabs at the bottom very easy, I've made a small sample as an example on how you may approach this. You can find the sample here  https://gist.github.com/luksprog/066f81f5e20c2ca41b7d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link : [Placing my ActionBar at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220428/placing-my-actionbar-at-the-bottom)

The google default action bar does not in any case appear on the bottom. As it seems others have mentioned, splitActionBarWhenNarrow only puts a subset of your ActionBar (like tabs, etc) on the bottom of the screen when the device is narrow. Unfortunately, if you want to implement an ActionBar like interface on the bottom of the screen, you'll have to implement it yourself (a quick search finds this example), as I haven't seen any Libraries to do this for you.

In all, though, I would recommend against it, as it violates the Seamlessness design principle in the design documents by breaking user expectations of where ActionBar type controls will be - An android user is ideally used to doing things a certain way, and you would need a pretty compelling reason to break that expectation.

`too see this link :` http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar

`and here is a sample :` http://android-ed.blogspot.com/2011/12/using-actionbar-at-bottom-of-screen.html